# Import partial sass doesn't work on sublime

Tags: import, sass

when trying for the first time importing a partial .scss works, but now it doesn't work!

I make a new .scss file with underscore and @import "_file.scss"; on the main .scss but it doesn't work now on Sublime..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you compile scss? How do you release that it doesn't work? Show your file structure.

Comment: Give to us more information.